# Compiler messages in Julia

Tags: julia

Consider the following code:

File C.jl

```
module C

export printLength

printLength = function(arr)
    println(lentgh(arr))
end

end #module
```

File Main.jl

```
using C

main = function()
    arr = Array(Int64, 4)
    printLength(arr)
end

main()
```

Let's try to execute it.

```
$ julia Main.jl 
ERROR: lentgh not defined
 in include at /usr/bin/../lib64/julia/sys.so
 in process_options at /usr/bin/../lib64/julia/sys.so
 in _start at /usr/bin/../lib64/julia/sys.so
while loading /home/grzes/julia_sucks/Main.jl, in expression starting on line 8
```

Obviously, it doesn't compile, because `lentgh` is misspelled. The problem is the message I received. `expression starting on line 8` is simply `main()`. Julia  hopelessly fails to point the invalid code fragment -- it just points to the invocation of `main`, but the erroneous line is not even in that file! Now imagine a real project where an error hides really deep in the call stack. Julia still wouldn't tell anything more than that the problem started on the entry point of the execution. It is impossible to work like that...

Is there a way to force Julia to give a little more precise messages?

Comment: Not entirely related to your question but you are creating anonymous functions with your definitions which are typically not very performant: https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/1864.  A more julian way would be something like `printLength(arr) = println(length(arr))`.  This won't improve the error message, just performance

Comment: Not that it's crucial, but julia code doesn't conventionally use camel case---underscores are preferred. And most julia code I've seen uses `function main()` rather than `main = function()`---as stated above, you'll get better performance.

Comment: I think I had this habit of writing `f = function()` from R. I didn't have an idea that it's a bad practice in Julia. Thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case it's almost certainly a consequence of inlining: your `printLength` function is so short, it's almost certainly inlined into the call site, which is why you get the line number 8.

Eventually, it is expected that inlining won't cause problems for backtraces. At the moment, your best bet---if you're running julia's pre-release 0.4 version---is to start julia as `julia --inline=no` and run your tests again.

Comment: I'm not convinced that this is just a matter of inlining -- for more complicated functions behavior is the same. Anyway, I compiled the latest version of julia from github (0.4.0-dev). This version precisely points to the erroneous line (even without `--inline=no`). Many thanks to all contributors :). I may acknowledge moving to version 0.4 as a solution.